# INSERT INTO with XML

Tags: xml, postgresql, select, insert

I am trying to create an INSERT INTO statement inserts data from an XML field, where a node contains '_01' and todays date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
    INSERT INTO productReference(preference, pcreatedon, customerID, id_number)
    SELECT preference, pcreatedon, customerID, CAST(xpath('/Product/id_number/text()', XMLProduct) as text[]) 
    FROM "dbProducts".tbl_ordereditems 
    WHERE CAST(xpath('/Product/id_number/text()', XMLProduct) as text) LIKE '%[_01]%'
    AND CAST(xpath('/Product/id_number/text()', XMLProduct) as text) LIKE CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS text)
    LIMIT 10;
```

I am getting the error could not parse XML document

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Show a sample of the document

Comment: What document? ................